# How to get all the rows using scan query criteria in hbase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, nosql

I have a hbase table and i am using a scan query table like below:

```
scan 'transaction', {COLUMNS=>'personal data:NAME', FILTER => "ValueFilter( =, 'binaryprefix:Christoph Benson' )"}
```

The output looks like :

```
hbase(main):021:0> scan 'transaction', {COLUMNS=>'personal data:NAME', FILTER => "ValueFilter( =, 'binaryprefix:Christoph Benson' )"}
ROW                                              COLUMN+CELL
 2470883371                                      column=personal data:NAME, timestamp=1439291965402, value=Christoph Benson
 2615494948                                      column=personal data:NAME, timestamp=1439291965312, value=Christoph Benson
 7526461715                                      column=personal data:NAME, timestamp=1439291965473, value=Christoph Benson
```

This result gives only **NAME**  information as I am using in scan query.
How do I query so that I can get all the information depending upon the scan query criteria.Something like below:

```
 personal data:NAME                              timestamp=1439291965402, value=Christoph Benson
 personal data:address                           timestamp=1439291965434, value=695 Keystone Parkway
 personal data:contact                           timestamp=1439291965418, value=153985171
 personal data:email                             timestamp=1439291965448, value=shoulddo@ma1lbox.net
```

Answer (score 0):

You could drop the `qualifier` in the `COLUMNS` to obtain all the data in a column family. i.e

`scan 'transaction', {COLUMNS=>'personal data', FILTER => "ValueFilter( =,      'binaryprefix:Christoph Benson' )"}`

Hope it helps.

Comment: What is the Hbase version that you are using?